# Sending visitor to different page depending on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I've done 3 separate pages for 1024, 768 and 320 width. Is there a way to send the visitor to the correct page depending on his screen resolution?

The reason I'm not building a responsive site is that it contains a Media Player that wont adapt the correct ratio :(

Thanks in advance :)
/Axel

Comment: `$(document).width()` + `window.location`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could You be a little more specific? 
Is it something like:
`code`
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).width() + window.location
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Window.Screen object to find out the height and width of Browser's window size.
You should do like this,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">       
</script>‌​
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = screen.availWidth;
//Now before comparison be sure you have only integer value
width = parseInt(width.toString());
var path='';
$(function(){
 if(width <= 320) 
 {
    path = "./320.html";
    loadWindow(path); 
  }
  else if (width > 320 && width <= 768) 
 {
   path = "./768.html";
   loadWindow(path); 
 }
 else if (width > 768 && width <= 1024) 
 {
   path = "./1024.html";
   loadWindow(path); 
  }
  else
  {
    path = "./1278.html";
    loadWindow(path); 
  }
});

//here is your loading function
function loadWindow(path)
{ 
   window.location.href = path;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tells me there's a syntax error on line 37 `function loadWindow(path)`

Comment: Could it be the paths which are wrong? The pages are all in the same folder should I still use `./1024.html`

Comment: using `"./1024.html"` or `"1024.html` works the same. But `./1024.html` make much more sense.

Comment: Hmm... Any ideas about the "Syntax error" with `function loadWindow(path)`

Comment: let me update my answer I found a bug there,
and sure you can just use 1024.html and other files if they are in same folder,

Comment: Tells me "no syntax errors" but still doesn't redirect me to any of the pages :( Does it work for you?

Comment: change loadWindow function to this one,
    function loadWindow(path)
    {
      window.location.href = path;

     }

Comment: Ah! Now it's redirecting but only to the `1278.htm`-page even if I set my window to 768..

Comment: `http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp` no they are right.. But try to use different methods for finding the width. Google for find a width of an element in jquery

Comment: If you want to navigate to any other page while you resize your page then you have to write .resize function to handle that,

Comment: Ahaa! Now I get it. It only works when I upload it and visit it from my computer, tablet or smartphone. Not when I just resize the browser window. Right?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for all of your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
var width = $( window ).width();

if(width <= 320) {
$(document).load("./320.html");
}
else if (width > 320 && width <= 768) {
$(document).load("./768.html");
}
else if (width > 768 && width <= 1024) {
$(document).load("./1024.html");
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the link to the different pages? Like 1024.htm, 768.htm, 320.htm? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can't get it to work. Do I need to exeute jquery?

`code`
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// Returns width of browser viewport
var width = $( window ).width();

if(width <= 320px) {
$(document).load("./320.html");
}
else if (width > 320 && width <= 768) {
$(document).load("./768.html");
}
else if (width > 768 && width <= 1024) {
$(document).load("./1024.html");
}
</script>
`code`

Comment: Tells me there is a Syntax error on line 11. Which is: `code`if(width <= 320px) {`code`
any ideas?

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` write this statement in head and then execute

Comment: Still telling me there's a synteax error on: if(width <= 320px) {

Comment: `width` returns an integer. `320px` is not an integer - change it to `320`

Comment: Syntax error removed but still not sending me to any site? Is it something with the "./" before the link?

Comment: Can't i do it somehow with: `code` if (screen.width <= 320) {
    window.location = "320.html";
  }
`code`

Answer (score 0):

You can build a html page with javascript, get the user device screen resolution with the follow javascript code:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

and redirect to the correct radio or page.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit rookie here. How do I write this if my pages are 1024.htm, 768.htm and 320.htm?